# How to close android application completely using adb or appium or any command line+python

Tags: android, shell, python-2.7, adb, appium

I have tried to close android application using adb command and appium server but it is minimizing the app, not closing. I used below command for closing.

> adb shell am force-stop com.package.name

AND if i try this command to kill process then it says,

> adb shell kill 21860

Error:Operation omitted

Please let me know any way or command line to close android app completely, not run in background.

Thanks in advance!

I don't want to see in the background application list like below image.[image]

Comment: No one has any suggestion for this question here?

Comment: you can use driver.close() since you are using appium. The app is closed even if it shows in background, it is not running. Or you can use find_element and clear it for your satisfaction

Answer (score -1):

```
adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE-NAME>
```

Force stopS everything associated with `<PACKAGE-NAME>`

should work since honeycomb

Comment: forgot to mention: command should be followed by the package name

Comment: It is stopping the application process but when i see in background it is showing application there. you can see in above picture.

Comment: I have tried this command and like the original poster said all it does it MINIMIZE the current or FOREGROUND app. It doesn't kill or force stop any app.

Answer (score -1):

*Why not just*:

1. un-installing app (it will stop any service or running process of it):

> 

```
adb -s <udid> uninstall <appPackage>
```

2. and then installing it again:

> 

```
adb -s <udid> install <apkPath>
```

**Note**:

In my case it is not working, because my app need to be registered each time re-installed, and working around it with 3rd app (e.g. Appium) is taking too long.